# CodePipeline in AWS gets Auto Triggered when Created from Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codepipeline, infrastructure-as-code, aws-cloud9

As part of my requirement I am trying to create a AWS CodePipeline from Terraform and Trigger the CodePipeline Manually once created. But Unfortunately the CodePipeline is getting triggered automatically once created from Terraform

I am Trying to find a way to stop the Codepipeline from triggering automatically as soon as it is deployed from Terraform.
I was trying to do one of the below 2 methods, But I did not find anything relevant for the same.

1. Find any Parameter which sets the auto trigger to false.
2. Or Enable the "DisableInboundStageTransitions" between the Source and the First Stage. So the pipeline stage's will not run even if the source has started.

I see "DisableInboundStageTransitions" is available in CloudFormation but not in Terraform.

It Would be really great if someone can let me know that is it even possible to do the above from Terraform?
Is there any workaround to Achieve the same?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using the `local-exec` [provisioner](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) in terraform to stop the execution immediately after pipeline creation. The user of `terraform` must also have awscli installed and configured, and `jq` installed.

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "my_pipeline" {
  name     = "my-deploy"
  ...etc...

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
aws codepipeline stop-pipeline-execution \
  --pipeline-name ${aws_codepipeline.my_pipeline.name} \
  --pipeline-execution-id $( \
    aws codepipeline list-pipeline-executions \
      --pipeline-name ${aws_codepipeline.my_pipeline.name} \
    | jq -r '.pipelineExecutionSummaries[].pipelineExecutionId' \
  )
EOT
  }
}
```

The script above was hastily built and may have to be adjusted if;

- There is no execution to stop.
- There is more than one execution to stop.
- There is one execution but its `status` is not `InProgress`.
- Stopping the execution fails.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**DetectChanges** attribute can be utilized within the code pipeline resource block, and it has been effective for me. Ensure that you provide either a true or false value. You can find an image representation of this attribute below.

[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsZeD.png)